# Drupal 8 - Loading a library globally from a custom module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I've create the library (**example-libraries.yml**):

```
example:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/example.js: {}
  css:
    theme:
      css/example.css: {}
```

I've tried to load it globally by doing this (**example.info.yml**):

```
name: Example Module
type: module
description: "A module that is responsible for ..."
package: Custom

core: 8.x
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT

libraries:
  - example/example
```

I can load it successfully for a particular Form by doing:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'example/example';
```

Any idea on how I can get it to work globally?

Answer (score 1):

I've finally figured that out. My custom module will place an extra tab as a child of the **system.admin** menu. Every other tab had an icon and I wanted to place my custom module icon there as well.

In case somebody else gets stuck with the same problem, in the file **example.module**, I had to create an entry:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_toolbar().
 */
function example_toolbar() {
    $items['example'] = array(
        '#type' => 'toolbar_item',
        '#attached' => array(
            'library' => array(
                'example/example',
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple in your my_theme.info.yml you add :

```
libraries:
```

- example/example

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/defining-a-theme-with-an-infoyml-file

Comment: Do I need to create t custom theme for that? My intent was to have only one module.

Comment: Yes you need a custom theme. It is easy and fast to create it. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom theme for this. Use [hook_page_attachments()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.2.x):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function example_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'example/example';
}
```

Comment: I am new to Drupal8 and as for now, my global settings are all in yml files. Where should I add that piece of code so that my library will be available globally?

Comment: put it into your example.module file